# Jquery Append on Click doesn't work. It instantly remove appended item

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, append

I have two select tags. When I click a link, I want the chosen option get appended to the other select, but after it appends it remove it instantly. Heres my code.

```
<select id="senroll" multiple="multiple" name="esubject">

</select><br /><br />
<label for="lsubject">Subject List</label></br>
<select id="slist" multiple="multiple" name="lsubject">
  <?php foreach($slist as $subject): ?>
      <?php echo "<option value='" . $subject['s_id'] . "'>" .   
       $subject['sname'] . "</option>"; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select><br /><br />   
<a href="" id="enroll">Enroll</a>
<a href="" id="drop">Remove</a>
```

Here my jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#enroll').on('click',  function(){

        var id = $('#slist').val();
        var snames = '#slist option[value="' + id + '"]';

        var sname = $(snames).text();
        var app = '<option value="' + id + '">' + sname + '</option>';
        $('#senroll').append(app);
        });
});
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. Tested in chrome.

Comment: it doesn't work with me. Idk the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#enroll').on('click',  function(){
        var id = $('#slist').val()[0];
        if(id){
            var snames = '#slist option[value="' + id + '"]';
          var sname = $(snames).text();
          var app = '<option value="' + id + '">' + sname + '</option>';
          $('#senroll').append(app);
        } 
        });
});
```

Comment: Something like this bro but a link should be click before appending the selected item

Comment: @ampol Where is the link, can you share the full code?

Comment: Thanks bro I've found my mistake it's the link. But why it doesn't work when i leave it blank?

Comment: @ampol You need to add an if condition to check if its having a value, if nothing is there, the select will have a value of `undefined` so you can just give `if(id)` where `id` will get validated to false, and the value will not get inserted!, updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#senroll").append($("<option></option>").val(1).html("One"));
    $("#senroll").append($("<option></option>").val(2).html("Two"));
    $("#senroll").append($("<option></option>").val(3).html("Three"));
    $('#senroll').on('click', function() {
        alert("I am clicked");
        var id = $('#slist').val()[0];
        var snames = '#slist option[value="' + id + '"]';
        console.log(id, snames);
        var sname = $(snames).text();
        console.log(sname);
        var app = '<option value="' + id + '">' + sname + '</option>';
        $('#enroll').append(app);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="senroll" multiple="multiple" name="esubject">
</select><br /><br />
<label for="lsubject">Subject List</label></br>
<select id="slist" multiple="multiple" name="lsubject">
  <?php foreach($slist as $subject): ?>
      <?php echo "<option value='" . $subject['s_id'] . "'>" .   
       $subject['sname'] . "</option>"; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select><br /><br />
```

I don't know more about `PHP` for each but this will work in your `js` Code

Hope this helps!